# NetBeans8 doesn't coloring GlassFish's output log anymore

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, glassfish, netbeans-8

Up to version NetBeans 8.0RC1 output log coloring was working just fine. It was coloring fine/finer/finest entries in green, config/info in gray, warning and up in red.

NetBeans 8.0 shows logs in plain black.

I noticed one difference - NB8 started to show log entry levels in lower case, while pervious versions - all upper case.

NetBeans 8.0RC and before:

`INFO: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [https-certificate] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8443]
WARNING: WEB0309: Unrecognized cipher: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`

("INFO" line in gray, "WARNING" line in red)

NetBeans 8.0:

`Info: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [https-certificate] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8443]
Warning: WEB0309: Unrecognized cipher: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`

(all lines in black)

I tried it on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and GlassFish 4.

Is that a new feature? Do I have to configure colors somehow? Or it's just a bug?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X (10.9.2), the problem seems to be related to Java 8. That is, when using NetBeans 8 or even 7.4 running on Java 8, I have the problem, but as soon as I switch back to Java 7, output log coloring with Glassfish works fine again on both NetBeans 8 and 7.4.

Comment: I reported this issue to the NetBeans development team: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243906

Answer (score 0):

This should work like before. I use Netbeans 8.0 on Windows and on Ubuntu and it works in both cases as usual ([here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6862316/so/color.png) is a screenshot).

Maybe something has changed your color settings. To set up the colors for the console window right-click in the console window and choose `Settings`.

If the colors seem to be set up correctly you can nonetheless try the `Restore` button.

If this doesn't help maybe a clean reinstall may solve the problem or you can try the latest nightly build of Netbeans 8 from http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/latest/

Comment: I have same issue with NB8 installed on two Windows7 workstations, so I doubt reinstall will help. I tried to settings/restore - doesn't help. I will try latest nightly build to see if it's been fixed.

Comment: I just tried nightly build 201403260001 - same issue. I installed it clean, didn't import config from previous installations when prompted. Still no colors.

Comment: Hmm strange stuff...does it work if you switch back to Netbeans 8 RC?

Comment: Yes, NB8 RC works fine, but again - there's something different about it - RC as well as previous versions show log levels in capitals. NB8 release turned levels to lowercase and logs seems stopped recognizing levels in lowercase. Interestingly in the beginning of log I saw copule of warning entries leaked with all capitals and nb8 did recognize it and displayed in red.